# Mediapipe Hand Tracking Module

Tags: python, mediapipe

Hey everyone I keep getting an error when I run this code. I wrote this code from a online YouTube video about hand detection (Mediapipe), in the video there was no issue so I just assumed I missed something I have spent several hours trying to research and find the seemingly small error but being a beginner I can seem to get it, if you can please help me out here.

Video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZde8Xt78Iw

Thank you

--------------------------------Code Below------------------------------------------------

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector:
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):

        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks(handNo)
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append(id, cx, cy)
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

        return lmList


def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)

        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

---------------------Error Code Below------------------------
C:\Users\kimsa\PycharmProjects\ROBO\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/kimsa/PycharmProjects/ROBO/HandTrackingModule.py
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kimsa/PycharmProjects/ROBO/HandTrackingModule.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kimsa/PycharmProjects/ROBO/HandTrackingModule.py", line 54, in main
    img = detector.findHands(img)
TypeError: findHands() missing 1 required positional argument: 'img'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Don't you want the statement to read```img = handDetector.findHands(img)```

Comment: Correct, That is why handDetector() is defined in the main() function as detector = handDetector. 
Just to be sure i went ahead and ran the program with img = handDetector.findHands(img) and got the same error message. 
Thank you for the input.

Comment: What is your error message?  What

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kimsa/PycharmProjects/ROBO/HandTrackingModule.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kimsa/PycharmProjects/ROBO/HandTrackingModule.py", line 54, in main
    img = detector.findHands(img)
TypeError: findHands() missing 1 required positional argument: 'img'

Comment: This is the error that shows up when I try to run the code...let me know if this is helpful

Comment: What is purpose of findHands method, since you return the imag variable that was used in the call without any alterations or modifications?  Also, what is the type and content of the imag returned from ```success, img = cap.read()```?

Comment: findHands( ) method takes the img captured from the main( ) method -> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1).  converts to gray scale -> imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).  the remaining code uses the mediapipe lib to draw landmarks provided there is a img available.

Comment: Should the statement ```self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)``` be rewritten as ```self.hands = mp.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)```?

Comment: I did run the program with that modification, how ever i still have the same error. 
What i cant understand is why is the error showing that i am missing a "argument" in this case img, when i have already pass that value in, could it be the way i have structured my code that img is not being  return to the proper method.

Comment: itproh66 i really appreciate you helping me with this

Comment: What happens if you step through your code with a debugger?  Can you trace the variable imag and ensure it is what you want at each stage?

Comment: running the debugger shows that img = detector.findHands(img) = None

Comment: just to be sure after succes, img = cap.read( )  Input this print statement  -> 
if not success: print("no Image")   continue

Comment: what does the debugger show the content of the variable img to be just before the call to ```detector.find(img)```?

Comment: 'no image' was printed out...so meaning that the main( ) method is not receiving the returned img from findHands( )....correct?

Comment: it shows that at success, img = cap.read( ) (success = bool False & img = NoneType None